# Can AudioTrack play MIDI files?

Tags: android, midi

I want to know can AudioTrack Android play MIDI file?

If not, which library can. Because I want the Android library which 
can play and control tempo of MIDI file for my app.

Comment: _"can AudioTrack Android play MIDI file?"_, No. It plays uncompressed PCM.

Comment: Please read the docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

Comment: Thank you Michael and 2Dee for you're answer.

Answer (score 9):

Check Android Supported media format from here [Android Media Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). MIDI playback support is built-in in Android. Playing MIDI file using [JetPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer.html) is very much handy in android. To play MIDI file you have to write code of below :

```
JetPlayer jetPlayer = JetPlayer.getJetPlayer();
jetPlayer.loadJetFile("/sdcard/level1.jet");
byte segmentId = 0;
// queue segment 5, repeat once, use General MIDI, transpose by -1 octave
jetPlayer.queueJetSegment(5, -1, 1, -1, 0, segmentId++);
jetPlayer.play();
```

For details check [Example 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_jetplayer.htm) & [Example 2](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/media/java/android/media/JetPlayer.java.shtml). And here is the [jet creator manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jet/jetcreator_manual.html) which will provide you the details background process of JetPlayer.

Comment: Can JetPlayer control the tempo (or speed) of MIDI file?

Answer (score 0):

A good [sample code to play MIDI file with Audio player in Android](http://web.archive.org/web/20170724134542/http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/11/simple-exercise-to-play-midi-audio.html)...

Hope it helps you .. :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) can become invalid if the linked page changes.